# one object control by all network players

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one object that can be control by all network player but the problem is the object is only control by single player who instantiated first on network
I have attaced netwrok transform and identity component on the object and also this script.

```
void Update () {

    CmdMove();

}

[Command]
void CmdMove() {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5 * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Comment: There's one Tank demo that is about Networking. He fixes what you are trying to instigate. Have a look on YouTube for it.

Comment: Don't you exactly what is wrong with above code. it should need to be wroked on input by any user. strange

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. And I cannot find the video I know I watched some weeks back.